# Configuring Base Auth on IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I want the browser to not retain username and password. How do I do?

Comment: You're gonna have to be a little more specific in your description than that

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Basic" auth, then there's nothing that you can do.

HTML forms can dictate that a browser should not retain a password, but there's no mechanism to do this for Basic auth.